# Java executorsevice is closing even its threads are running

Tags: java, jdbc

I am Using Executorsevice to generate files from database. I am using `jdbc` and core `java` to get the table data into files.

After creating the Executorservice with 10 threads I am submitting 60 threads in a for loop  to get 60 files parallelly.  This is working fine with small data and a table with few columns. But in case of a huge file and for tables having more columns,  the thread which is working on huge table data/ more columns table is stopping without giving any information in the log when the other threads are completed .

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_COUNT);
        for (String filename : filenames) {
            EachFileThread worker = new EachFileThread(destdir, converter,
                    filename, this);
            executor.execute(worker);
        }
        executor.shutdown();
```

Inside Eachfilethread I am reading the xml and get columns, table and form a query and executing the query and formatting the data and putting the data into file

```
    forTable = (FileData) converter.convertFromXMLToObject( filename + ".xml");
    String query = getQuery(forTable);
    statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
resultSet.setFetchSize(3000);
    WriteData(resultSet, filepath, forTable);(formatting the data from db and then writing to a file)
```

Comment: Adding your code would help debugging.

Comment: Can you add your EachFileThread code ?

Comment: You probably need to call `awaitTermination(...)` to wait for all the threads to complete.

Comment: @vardhan I don't see any issues with the code. Can you post `EachFileThread` as well.

Comment: added code, I am thinking the way i used execute service is the problem,or ES will give anystatus of each threads i need to check

Comment: `ExecutorService` doesn't seem to have any function that let you check if all the jobs have finished. To do it this way you would probably need to make use of `submit(task)` method which returns [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) and wait until all the returned Futures complete (`future.get()` or `future.isDone()`)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not waiting for all the jobs to finish what they were doing. As @msandiford suggested in the comment you should add call to [`awaitTermination(..)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) after calling [`shutdown()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) as it is in sample `shutdownAndAwaitTermination()` method on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

For example you can try to do it like so:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_COUNT);
for (String filename : filenames) {
    EachFileThread worker = new EachFileThread(destdir, converter, filename, this);
    executor.execute(worker);
}
executor.shutdown();
try {
    // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
    if (!executor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
        executor.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
        // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
        if (!executor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            System.err.println("Executor did not terminate");
    }
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
    executor.shutdownNow();
    // Preserve interrupt status
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

Comment: it didnt worked, that thread is should write a file almost 6gb,its generating 0 kb file. when i ran individually its working fine.

Comment: @vardhan the sample code has timeout of 1 minute, maybe it is too short for all your jobs to finish. How long does it take for that job to finish when you run it individually?

Comment: this code will take 20 minutes if file is more size or table has crores of data or else it will take less time only.

Comment: Then adjust the timeouts according to your needs. By replacing `executor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` with something like `executor.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)`